The update portion of my snowflake streamlit app does not work
I have created a snowflake streamlit app to writeback data into a table, the insert works fine, the search function work fine, but it does not update the data as expected
# Section for searching and updating existing records
st.subheader("Search for Record to Update")
with st.form("search_record"):
    search_by = st.radio("Search by:", ('MCC Code', 'MCC_TITLE'))
    search_value = st.text_input(f"Enter {search_by}:")
    search_button = st.form_submit_button('Search')

# Display and update form if record is found
if search_button:
    try:
        search_column = '"MCC Code:"' if search_by == 'MCC Code' else '"MCC_TITLE"'
        query = f"""
        SELECT * FROM IK_DEV.POWER_WRITE_BACK.MERCHANT_CATEGORY_CODE_LIST
        WHERE {search_column} = '{search_value}'
        """
        df_search_result = session.sql(query).to_pandas()
        if not df_search_result.empty:
            st.success("Record found!", icon="✅")
            record = df_search_result.iloc[0]

            with st.form("update_record"):
                mcc_code = st.text_input('MCC Code:', value=record['MCC Code:'])
                mcc_title = st.text_input('MCC Title:', value=record['MCC_TITLE'])
                ikhokha_defined = st.text_input('iKhokha Defined:', value=record['iKhokha defined (What our customers see)'])
                mcc_description = st.text_area('MCC Description:', value=record['MCC_DESCRIPTION'])
                included_in_this_mcc = st.text_input('Included in this MCC:', value=record['INCLUDED_IN_THIS_MCC'])
                similar_merchants = st.text_input('Similar Merchants:', value=record['SIMILAR_MERCHANTS'])
                restricted_cp = st.checkbox('Restricted CP', value=record['RESTRICTED_CP'] == 1)
                restricted_cnp = st.checkbox('Restricted CNP', value=record['RESTRICTED_CNP'] == 1)
                update_button = st.form_submit_button('Update')

            if update_button:
                try:
                    restricted_cp_int = 1 if restricted_cp else 0
                    restricted_cnp_int = 1 if restricted_cnp else 0

                    update_query = f"""
                    UPDATE IK_DEV.POWER_WRITE_BACK.MERCHANT_CATEGORY_CODE_LIST
                    SET "MCC Code:" = '{mcc_code}', "MCC_TITLE" = '{mcc_title}', "iKhokha defined (What our customers see)" = '{ikhokha_defined}', 
                        "MCC_DESCRIPTION" = '{mcc_description}', "INCLUDED_IN_THIS_MCC" = '{included_in_this_mcc}', "SIMILAR_MERCHANTS" = '{similar_merchants}', 
                        "RESTRICTED_CP" = {restricted_cp_int}, "RESTRICTED_CNP" = {restricted_cnp_int}
                    WHERE {search_column} = '{search_value}'
                    """
                    session.sql(update_query).collect()
                    st.success('Record successfully updated!', icon="✅")
                except Exception as e:
                    st.error(f"Error updating record: {e}")
        else:
            st.error("No record found!", icon="❌")
    except Exception as e:
        st.error(f"Error searching for record: {e}")

I tried the above but when I check the table no update of the existing record has taken place
I have made the below changes
# Display and update form if record is found
if search_button:
    try:
        search_column = '"MCC Code:"' if search_by == 'MCC Code' else '"MCC_TITLE"'
        query = f"""
        SELECT * FROM IK_DEV.POWER_WRITE_BACK.MERCHANT_CATEGORY_CODE_LIST
        WHERE {search_column} = '{search_value}'
        """
        df_search_result = session.sql(query).to_pandas()
        if not df_search_result.empty:
            st.success("Record found!", icon="✅")
            record = df_search_result.iloc[0]

            with st.form("update_record"):
                mcc_code = st.text_input('MCC Code:', value=record['MCC Code:'])
                mcc_title = st.text_input('MCC Title:', value=record['MCC_TITLE'])
                ikhokha_defined = st.text_input('iKhokha Defined:', value=record['iKhokha defined (What our customers see)'])
                mcc_description = st.text_area('MCC Description:', value=record['MCC_DESCRIPTION'])
                included_in_this_mcc = st.text_input('Included in this MCC:', value=record['INCLUDED_IN_THIS_MCC'])
                similar_merchants = st.text_input('Similar Merchants:', value=record['SIMILAR_MERCHANTS'])
                restricted_cp = st.checkbox('Restricted CP', value=record['RESTRICTED_CP'] == 1)
                restricted_cnp = st.checkbox('Restricted CNP', value=record['RESTRICTED_CNP'] == 1)
                update_button = st.form_submit_button('Update')

                if update_button:
                    try:
                        restricted_cp_int = 1 if restricted_cp else 0
                        restricted_cnp_int = 1 if restricted_cnp else 0

                        update_query = f"""
                        UPDATE IK_DEV.POWER_WRITE_BACK.MERCHANT_CATEGORY_CODE_LIST
                        SET "MCC Code:" = '{mcc_code}', "MCC_TITLE" = '{mcc_title}', "iKhokha defined (What our customers see)" = '{ikhokha_defined}', 
                        "MCC_DESCRIPTION" = '{mcc_description}', "INCLUDED_IN_THIS_MCC" = '{included_in_this_mcc}', "SIMILAR_MERCHANTS" = '{similar_merchants}', 
                        "RESTRICTED_CP" = {restricted_cp_int}, "RESTRICTED_CNP" = {restricted_cnp_int}
                        WHERE {search_column} = '{search_value}'
                        """

                        st.write(update_query)
                        result_df = session.sql(update_query).collect()
                        st.dataframe(result_df)
                        st.success('Record successfully updated!', icon="✅")
                    except Exception as e:
                        st.error(f"Error updating record: {e}")
        else:
            st.error("No record found!", icon="❌")
    except Exception as e:
        st.error(f"Error searching for record: {e}")

Still no luck its as if it still does not enter the if update_button:

3 suggestions: (1) st.write(update_query) to verify the final formatted SQL (2) session.sql returnd a dataframe, so capture it as: result_df = session.sql.... and then display the df after the session.sql statement (3) The if update_button should be indented under the with st.form statement

3 suggestions

st.write(update_query) to verify the final formatted SQL
session.sql returns a dataframe, so capture it as: result_df = session.sql.... and then display the df after the session.sql statement
The if update_button should be indented under the with st.form statement


Hi Dave, I made the changes but still no luck its as if it does not enter the '' if update_button: '' block

changes are made as per above

Does the final formatted SQL in the st.write(update_query) look correct? Are there any rows in the result_df dataframe? Note that these are just debugging steps that would not be required in the final app.

Dave, apologies for the late reply
I dont get a st.write(update_query) print out as if the submit button never evaluates to True

I hard coded it to true which prints out an script that I can run manually and it updates correct. Its although there is a bug, with the event driven logic for the streamlit app
